# When rewriting image url via htaccess, image is broken

Tags: image, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Ok so I have written a successful htaccess redirect, but there is a problem. What it does correctly is if someone directly tries to access an image, then instead of viewing the raw image it takes them to the image attachment page.

Here is my htaccess code:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.jpg   http://myblog.com/?attachment=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^files/2016/12/([^.]+)\.(jpg|jpeg|png|bmp|gif)$   http://myblog.com/?attachment=$1/ [L]
```

Here is the problem: On the image attachment page, it actually shows a broken image where the image url is, even though when I look at the source code, the image url is correct. Something is wrong.

See this screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rpixy.jpg

The whole page loads fine including all other images and content. <s>The only thing that doesn't work is the original image.</s> All images are broken beginning in `files/2016/12/`

This url shown in the inspection window for the image is the correct image url, and absent the htaccess code, this url goes directly to the image.

Even if I reload the page manually, it still shows the broken image. However, if I remove the htaccess code and reload the page, the image shows up, so the attachment page URL is correct.

How do I fix this? Thank you.

Edit: I think I could solve this by adding a filter than makes it so this is only run it it is referred. In fact that would be better I think. Basically, if it is ANY referrer other than the domain where the image is hosted, then it will run the redirect. How can I do that?

Comment: It sounds like your rules are doing exactly what it looks like they should do, you just don't understand them. You're using full URLs in the substitutions, but you're missing the `R` flag. They're very broad rules; if you only want to redirect when the referer is not your own site, add a `RewriteCond` for it.

Comment: Didn't work sadly. And yes I do understand what it does.

Comment: The `R` flag wasn't a solution. I don't think you do; you're rewriting all URLs with `.jpg` in them to an attachment page, then wondering why a page has images that aren't showing. Apache has no idea whether a URL is requested via a browser's address bar or from an `<img>` tag, so it's gonna keep rewriting everything.

Comment: no you are wrong, I am not rewriting all .jpg. It seems it is you that does not understand what is going on.

Comment: Haha, no *you* are wrong. That's why you're the one asking questions. Maybe you don't *intend* to rewrite all `.jpg` URLs, but your first condition + rule do exactly that. To translate your PCRE: all URLs that contain `.jpg` *anywhere*, but not `.php` will be redirected (inefficiently) to the attachment page. You still seem confused about redirects, either add the `R` flag, or, for internal rewrites remove the scheme, domain and first `/` in the substitution. Conditions only apply the the next rule, so your second rule isn't using one. (In case you meant it to.)